# Semantic issue undeclared identifier Utilities

Tags: ios

I want to make the object of NSUrl in following way but **Utilities** is undefined.

Please someone tell me If i want to use Utilities class then which framework have to include in our project.

```
NSString* outputFileName = @"outputFile.mov";
NSString* outputFilePath = [Utilities documentsPath:outputFileName];
NSURL*    outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
```

Comment: This Utilities class is not a standart class from Apple's frameworks. You are probably looking at some example code where this **Utilities** class is implemented. If you want to use it you have copy Utilities.m and Utilities.h files to your project and #import "Utilities.h" wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/movie.m4v"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

More easy

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"outputFile" ofType:@"mov"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I know about, but what you are probably looking for is the path to the application documents directory

given by...

```
NSString *docspath =  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString* outputFilePath = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputFileName];
```